# Selenium Python - dealing with checkboxes is_selected()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have simple python code presented on the picture.
The thing is that eula checkbox is making me problems.
I am trying not to check it if it is not selected and to ignore checking if it is.

But, if I don't use eula variable on line 41 I get an error: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.

If I uncomment this line and use it, than this if block doesn't work and my checkbox gets unchecked.

[python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmZnt.png)
[html structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJDf1.png)

Comment: Please share code and html in text format also

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  And please...no screeenshots.

Comment: It is highly possible that when you click the Login button, your page reloads. So you HAVE to get your checkbox element again as the old one has gone stale. And for the problem where your if block is not working as expected, sharing url will be very helpful. And please share actual code/html in question instead of images of it.

Answer (score 1):

If your checkbox `checked="checked"`.So you need to check first whether selected or not.If selected do not click.Try this code.

```
element=driver.find_element_by_id("eulaAccepted")
if element.is_selected():
    print('Check box is already selected')
else:
    element.click()
```

Comment: No, it still does the same thing. 
Haven't I checked if the checkbox is selected using the: if not eula.is_selected()??

Comment: Are you still getting the stale exception?

Comment: Since I have no access to your application and you html is not clear i can't say whats wrong in that but are you sure you have copied my code.I mean if you see my element is different than yours that is why asked.